# Gccv5.4 undefined reference to `__normal___udivdi3'

Tags: gcc, u-boot

I have updated the gcc from version 4.6 to 5.4. To be clear, I have both the versions I am using the sudo update-alternatives --config g++ to switch between the versions.

```
vies7605@eso9265:~/Projects/u-boot/u-boot-x86$ sudo update-alternatives --config g++
There are 2 choices for the alternative g++ (providing /usr/bin/g++).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/g++-4.6   20        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/g++-4.6   20        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/g++-5     20        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 

vies7605@eso9265:~/Projects/u-boot/u-boot-x86$ sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
There are 2 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gcc-4.6   20        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gcc-4.6   20        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/gcc-5     20        manual mode
```

I am building the u-boot source code(latest git version x86), with the gcc compiler. When I am using the version 4.6 the build is fine.
But when I use the gcc version 5.4 the build fails with the error message,

```
arch/x86/lib/built-in.o: In function `__wrap___udivdi3':
/home/vies7605/Projects/u-boot/u-boot-x86/arch/x86/lib/gcc.c:25: undefined reference to `__normal___udivdi3'
make: *** [u-boot] Error 1
```

I am not sure why this is happening, any help on this topic will be helpful.

```
vies7605@eso9265:~/Projects/u-boot/u-boot-x86$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-3ubuntu1~12.04) 5.4.0 20160603
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is my laptop is 64 bit system and the u-boot is built in 32 bit mode for Minnowboard target(x86)

Installing multilib version of gcc , solves the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-6-multilib g++-6-multilib 
sudo apt-get install gcc-5-multilib g++-5-multilib
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not have CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC set.

Comment: No. its enabled in the config files ./configs/minnowmax_defconfig:CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC=y

Comment: OK, interesting.  What version of U-Boot are you using?  I build all of x86 but with gcc-5.3 not 5.4 almost daily.

Comment: The build with gcc-4.6 is fine but with gcc-5.4 the build is breaking, the u-boot is v2016.07-rc1-271-g9f82361